# Proof that for $S \subseteq T \subseteq M$, $S$ open in $T \Rightarrow$ there is an open set $U$ such that $S=T\cap U$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

There are many proofs on stack exchange of this result, however all make use of something along the lines of:

$$\forall s\in S, \exists \varepsilon_s >0 \text{ such that } B_T(s,\varepsilon_s)\subseteq S, \text{ so } S=\left(\bigcup_s B(s,\varepsilon_s )\right)\cap T$$

Why can we not just set $U=S$ and then trivially have $S=T\cap S$, since we are working under the assumption that $S$ is open?

I've tried working through this and I think what I'm missing is something to do with whether $S$ is open in $M$ or just in $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your last sentence: your confusion is coming from the difference between "open in $T$" vs "open in $M$".

In the claim we're proving, if we assume $U$ needs to be open in $T$, then your argument works and that's the easiest proof for that case.

Probably the other proofs you're looking at are proving it works even if we require $U$ to be open in $M$. Your "something along the lines of..." statement is probably a reasonable proof of that version, depending on how you set up your definitions. (Actually, in the most common definition this new claim would be totally trivial: Wikipedia [*defines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) "$S$ is open in $T$" to exactly mean "There is some $U$ open in $M$ such that $T \cap U = S$".)